# Pandas Dataframe - Replace all cell value subject to regex condition

Tags: python, pandas, regexp-replace

I am solving a question where in a column  there are few values which are repetitions of "." , eg-"....." or"............." .

So I want to use the `.loc` function to replace all such values by `np.NaN`.
I want to use the regex function to identify any cell value having at least one repetition of `"."`.

So i used the below code in Python -

```
energy.loc[bool(re.match('.+', energy['Energy Supply'])),'Energy Supply']=np.NaN
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot as below as the dot represents any character and the plus is one or more, give that a try :)

`re.match('\.+', energy['Energy Supply']))`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check for a dot, and escape it to match it literally.

You don't need the `+` quantifier because it means 1 or more. So matching a single dot is sufficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    "test",
    "test.",
    "..."
]
energy = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Energy Supply"])
energy.loc[energy['Energy Supply'].str.contains(r'\.'), 'Energy Supply'] = np.NaN
print(energy)
```

Output

```
  Energy Supply
0          test
1           NaN
2           NaN
```